# jquery datetimepicker format not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, date, datetime

I am using bootstrap datetime picker,when I try to set format to "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM" its not setting.When I enter date its changing to "YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM" but I need in the format "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM".The below is my code:

```js
$('#startDate').datetimepicker({
  dateFormat: 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm'
 });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/jquery.datetimepicker.css"></link>
<script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js"></script>

<input name="startDate" type="text" id="startDate"/>
```

Comment: If anyone here for finding bootstrap datetimepicker, this is not, this question is related to jquery datetimepicker, for bootstrap datetimepicker go to : [bootstrap-datetimepicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$('#startDate').datetimepicker({
    format: 'Y-m-d H:i'
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jn3j9ur3/

Answer (score 1):

Here Working [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/dhirenpateldev/b4get969/) !!!
Html:-

```
<input name="startDate" type="text" id="startDate"/>
```

Javascript:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#startDate').datetimepicker({
        format: 'Y-m-d H:i'
    
    });
  });
```

Hope Its Work !!!

Comment: Thanks , but your answer  not helped to me anyway.